# How to make simple messaging using socket.io and react useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I want to make simple messaging  using socket.io and react `useEffect()` for a setup but I have no idea on how to properly manage/update state from inside of `useEffect`.
This is my code:

```
  function App() {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{ type: "system", text: "Please stay nice!" }]);
    useEffect(() => {
      socket.current.on("messageSent", (data) => {
        setMessages([...messages, { type: "you", text: data.message }]);
      });

      socket.current.on("receiveMessage", (data) => {
        setMessages([...messages, { type: "partner", text: data.message }]);
      });
    }, []);

    return (
      <>
        <span className="container">
          <Chat messages={messages} />
        </span>
      </>
    );
  }
```

The point is I don't want to re-run `useEffect()`, I want it to run once at the beginning to set-up socket callbacks.
Right now when I try to access messages from inside of my `useEffect` I got only the starting value which is `[{ type: "system", text: "Please stay nice!" }]` also `setMessages` doesn't refresh `props` of my parent component and child component has only access to this starting value `[{ type: "system", text: "Please stay nice!" }]`.

Comment: Your useEffect seems to be set up correctly. When you say "setMessages()" doesn't affect the state, do you mean that that code is being reached? I think you are not sending your data to the socket listener correctly, and that "setMessages" never runs.

Comment: My socket connection works fine and I am sure setMessages is being called properly(I have tested this). I have updated my question(last part)

Comment: Your useEffect only runs once, when the component mounts, due to the fact that you give it an empty array as a second argument.

Try to write it like this instead:
`setMessages(prev => [...prev, { type: "you", text: data.message }]);`

Comment: Yes, you are right, write this as an answer and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: Great! If you are gonna set a state that is dependent on the previous state, always write it like that to make sure that you always get the latest state.